# Post image wordpress hidden

Tags: css, wordpress

I need a thumbnail for wordpress plugin wp-tiles. The plugin uses the menu to the last image of each post by default, the fact is that I would like to fit a picture to the size specifically for the plugin in use, but I wish they saw the image is not in the post, not occupy space and remain hidden. Is there any way? Thank you.

Comment: You're really going to have to post a link to the site or a fiddle because I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: What I need is to post an image in a wordpress post but did not see, only a thumbnail image for the plugin wp-tiles in use, but that is not shown in the post.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still can't really answer your question.